# Vlookup to return multiple matching values in different rows

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two columns A and B and wherever A matches B value from C is returned in Column D. I am using the following formula for this =VLOOKUP($A2, $B$2:$C$whatever, 2, 0). Also I can have any value in column A . It wont be always same as in the example.

What I am currently getting is this

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

Is there a way I can do this using vlookup or index?

Thanks in advance

Comment: seems to me a simple `=IF(A2=B2,C2,"")` would do it or do they not always line up?

Comment: yes that is not the always the case so it wont do it

Comment: Can you then change your mockup to show more?  Show when they are offset with other data and such.

Comment: The vlookup is returning the first value that matches... until you have index values that are unique then you have a problem...

Comment: Yes without a true data case it is not clear what your question is trying to do here. Right now all your column A & column B data is the same, making any analysis meaningless. Technically the correct way to answer with your current data layout is just "=C1", because the statement is true for all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$2:$B$5)/($B$2:$B$5=A2),COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it works. Could you tell me what 15 and 7 indicate?

Comment: yes leave those there and change the references only.