# What function can I use in Excel 2019 in lieu of Google Sheets 'FILTER'?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like the cells on sheet `MATRIX` from `A5` to `A120000` to display the dates on sheet `ALGORITHM` only if the corresponding column `C` on `ALGORITHM` is defined as **TRUE**

I have used the Google Sheets formula `FILTER` however I do not have that function in my version (2019) of Excel.

Would anyone be able to suggest an alternative to FILTER and a recommended formula?

[image: SHEET - MATRIX]

[image: SHEET - ALGORITHM]

Comment: Use `INDEX()` & `AGGREGATE()`

Comment: Lot of example here in Stackoverflow, one such [Return Multiple Records](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52763441/8162520)

Comment: [Look Here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bExcel%5d%20INDEX%20AGGREGATE)

Comment: So far I have the following: =IFERROR(INDEX(I5:I12000,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(C5:C12000="TRUE"),ROW(1:1))),"") But it not working yet

Comment: Should be like this, `=IFERROR(INDEX(I$5:I$12000,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(C$5:C$12000)-ROW(C$5)+1)/(C$5:C$12000=TRUE),ROW(A1))),"")` try and let us know

Comment: Unfortunately not. It returns 00 Jan 00 where it should return 26 Aug 22 and then 29 Aug 22 etc.

Comment: try this : `=IFERROR(INDEX(I$5:I$12000,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(C$5:C$12000)-ROW(C$5)+1)/(C$5:C$12000=TRUE),COUNTIF(C$5:C5,C5))),"")`

Comment: Still returns 00 Jan 00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is a quick example of the formula given in above comments,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$15,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$B$15)-ROW($B$2)+1)/($B$2:$B$15=TRUE),ROW(A1))),"")
```

And Fill Down !